# Как получить строку из QTextEdit?

Tags: c, qt, c++

Как в Qt4 получить строку из `QTextEdit` (если строк много, естественно)?

Answer (score 4):

Используйте символ конца строки:

```
QString str=ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
QStringList strList=str.split('\n'); // разбиваем строку из текстедита на отдельные строки
str=strList.at(1); // берем вторую строку
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
QTextEdit *test = new QTextEdit("нужная строка");
QString temp = test->getText();
// temp содержит значение "нужная строка"
//QString *temp = test->getText(); - возможно нужно с указателем
```

Comment: Нет, мне нужно получить определённую строку из формы, а не просто перевести в другой тип. Прочитайте внимательнее вопрос.

Comment: error: 'class QTextEdit' has no member named 'getText'

                                              ^